# What is the correct way to call std::to_chars?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to call `std::to_chars` on a double. My code doesn't compile on any compiler I have (gcc 10.2, clang 10.0.1).

Minimally reproducible code ([or on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PTfETn)):

```cpp
#include <charconv>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string str;
    str.resize(30);
    auto[ptr, ec] = std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), double(3.5));
}
```

I compiled with `-std=c++17`.
The error I'm getting is:

On gcc 10.2:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:7:83: error: call of overloaded 'to_chars(char*, char*, double)' is ambiguous
    7 |     auto[ptr, ec] = std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), double(3.5));
      |                                                                                   ^
In file included from <source>:1:
/.../gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/charconv:366:1: note: candidate: 'std::to_chars_result std::to_chars(char*, char*, char, int)'
...
```

and then it lists all candidates.

On clang 10.0.1, it pretty much just tells me:

```
<source>:7:21: error: no matching function for call to 'to_chars'
    auto[ptr, ec] = std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), double(3.5));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried all the overloads with `double` that are listed on [cppreference's page on `std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars), they all give different errors, but in the end nothing works.

I do not understand why the overload resolution is not clear when it should be clear, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

I want to add that MSVC does it fine without any errors.

Comment: It looks to me like `std::to_chars_result to_chars(char* first, char* last, double      value);` overload is not yet implemented in libc++ or libstdc++. Calling it with an `int` works.

Comment: @bolov Yeah, it works on MSVC just fine - seems weird, I thought gcc at least was fully c++17 compliant. Guess not?

Comment: Closing this is ridiculous. The "correct" answer would be that the way I called it IS correct, but gcc & clang haven't implemented it. It's not a duplicate and the "duplicate" doesn't answer my question even remotely.

Comment: @bolov: That duplicate doesn't answer the question. It merely states that implementing the functions is not trivial; that doesn't actually say whether any particular version of any particular compiler implements the function. The other question incidentally mentions that no vendors at that time implemented them, but even that statement is out of date.

Comment: Update: gcc 11 implements it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use is perfectly fine, and it compiles correctly under MSVC 19. As described in the [Microsoft Docs for the <charconv> functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/charconv-functions), this requires at least C++17.

As you can see for yourself in [The GNU C++ Library Manual, Chapter 1. Status, C++ 2017](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017), the last update regarding P0067R5 (Elementary string conversions, revision 5) was on GCC 8.1, with the comment "only integral types supported".

Similarly, [the libc++ C++17 Status](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html), defines P0067R5 as "Partially done".

If you need more evidence that this is a problem with your C++ implementation, look at the include file for your GCC/Clang installation and you will see that it doesn't define the floating-point overloads (they aren't defined for me, with GCC 10.2.1).

Comment: yes - you're right, the header doesnt even mention floating point values! thanks